# vim: only upper german umlaut broken

Tags: unix, vim, encoding, utf-8, solaris

I don't understand why opening an utf-8 textfile with vim on an "utf-8 machine" shows lowercase umlauts correct, but uppercase umlauts are broken (i.e. ▒~D instead of Ä) and thus I have no idea how to fix it.

The file is utf-8 encoded:

```
$ iconv -f UTF-8 myFile.txt > /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
```

Local settings are utf-8:

```
$ locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

All umlauts (uppercase and lowercase) are correct if the file is opened with vi instead of vim. Command-line tools get it right as well:

```
$ cat myFile.txt | grep Ä
//TEMPORÄR
```

I tried setting `encoding=utf-8` and `fileencoding=utf-8` in vim, but it had no effect and if it had i would'nt understand why, because it is definitly just a display Problem:

```
# Creating a file using vi, content:
ÄÖ

# Opening using vim displays:
▒~D▒~V

# Adding a new line using vim (by typing ÄÖ)
▒~D▒~V
▒~D▒~V

# Opening the same file using vi again
ÄÖ
ÄÖ
```

Using `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.1` on `Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 X86`, updating is *not* an option.

Any help would by appreciated, because my "googling" didn't help me so far.

( Workarround would be to configure `vi` to avoid "tmp file to large" or "line to long" errors, which are the main reasons i'd prefer vim. )

Comment: I don't have an answer but vim on Solaris (/opt/csw) is based different screen handling from vi. (libcurses versus libncurses).  And 7.1 is rather old - if you cannot update to 7.2 I would guess you are stuck with vi.

Comment: Thank you anyway! Didn't think about that before at all and as `ldd` says the same I fear you might be right.

Comment: Open the file in vim. What does ":set fileencoding" show?

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't seem to have any effect at all, not even `Unkown option` or whatever.

Comment: It is supposed to show the encoding of the file. What is the output if you do the same when you have opened the file in vi? @evilive

Comment: `fileencoding: No such option - 'set all' gives all option values`... I guess its rather old as well, though working . But why doing it anyway? Do you mistrust the encoding validation via iconv?